# Cómo obtener la hora del servidor

Tags: php, javascript

tengo un código que me muestra el tiempo restante a una fecha y hora establecidas por mí, pero solo sé hacerlo usando la hora local (la que tenga el usuario en el ordenador), pero yo necesito que se use la del servidor a la hora de calcular el tiempo.

Esta es una parte del código (con la hora local como referencia):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var target_date = new Date("May 17, 2018 20:18:20").getTime();
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

function timeLeft() {
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
setInterval(function () {
    var current_date = new Date().getTime(); //AQUÍ SE RECOGE LA HORA LOCAL DEL USUARIO
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

if (days >= 1) {
    temporizador.innerHTML = 'Faltan '  + days + ' días.';
} else if (hours >= 1) {
    temporizador.innerHTML = 'Faltan '  + hours + ' horas.';
} else if (minutes >= 1) {
    temporizador.innerHTML = 'Faltan '  + minutes + ' minutos.';
} else if (seconds >= 1) {
    temporizador.innerHTML = 'Faltan '  + seconds + ' segundos.';
} else {
    temporizador.innerHTML = 'Finalizado';
}

            }, 1000);

}

</script>
```

¿Alguien me ayuda a reemplazar eso por una variable que recoja la fecha del servidor?

Comment: La fecha del servidor solo esta disponible en el servidor.  Por lo tanto no puedes hacerlo en javascript.  Tendrias que hacerlo en PHP a menos que uses Ajax.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Agrega la fecha del servidor a un elemento del HTML de tu archivo PHP, por ejemplo si estas utilizando un index.php agrega un input y coloca en el value con PHP la hora del servidor con la función date():

```
<input id="serverDate" type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d')?>">
```

Después en tu archivo de javascript obtienes el value del input y lo pasas al constructor de Date

```
var serverDate = document.getElementById('serverDate').value; 

var target_date = new Date(serverDate).getTime();
```

Comment: Esta respuesta tampoco considera la diferencia horaria entre cliente (JS) y servidor (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente he tenido un problema/duda similar al respecto. 
Personalmente, no recomiendo que utilices la hora del servidor si vas a realizar un temporizador. Ya que deberías estar haciendo constantemente peticiones al servidor. La única solución que respondiese concretamente a tu petición sería pedir la fecha actual al servidor una vez, y a partir de ahí, mediante JS ir actualizando esa misma hora, añadiendole milisegundo a milisegundo. No sé hasta que punto puede ser viable esa opción.

Esta es la solución a la que yo he llegado, a mi manera :)

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    var tiempoRestante= undefined;  
    var timer;
    $.ajax({
        url : "./Controller/AuctionController.php",
        method: "POST",
        data : {"metodo":"tiempoSubasta", "codSubasta": $("#tiempoRestante").attr("data")}
    }).done(function (response){
        // console.log(response);
        var json = JSON.parse(response);
        tiempoRestante = json*1000;
        timer = setInterval(comprueba,1000);

    });



    function formatearTiempoRestante(fechaFin){
        var fechaActual = new Date();
    // Tomar todos los segundos que diferencian con respecto a la fecha final
        var dif = Math.abs(fechaFin - fechaActual) / 1000;

        // calcula y resta los dias
        var days = Math.floor(dif / 86400);
        dif -= days * 86400;

        // calcula y resta las horas
        var hours = Math.floor(dif / 3600) % 24;
        dif -= hours * 3600;

        // calcula y resta los minutos
        var minutes = Math.floor(dif / 60) % 60;
        dif -= minutes * 60;

        // lo que queda son segundos
        var seconds = Math.floor(dif % 60);

        return new Array(formatFechas(days, 10), formatFechas(hours, 10), formatFechas(minutes, 10), formatFechas(seconds, 10));
    }

    function comprueba (){
        if(tiempoRestante - (new Date()) <=0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            $("#tiempoRestante").text("SE ACABÓ");
        }else{
            var tiempo = formatearTiempoRestante(tiempoRestante);

            if(tiempo[0]<=0 && tiempo[1] <= 0 && tiempo[2] <=0 && tiempo[3] <=0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $("#tiempoRestante").text("SE ACABÓ");
            }else{
                $("#dias").text(tiempo[0]);
                $("#horas").text(tiempo[1]);
                $("#minutos").text(tiempo[2]);
                $("#segundos").text(tiempo[3]);
            }
        }


    }


});


function formatFechas(nr, base){
  var len = (String(base).length - String(nr).length) + 1;
  return len > 0? new Array(len).join('0') + nr : nr;
}`
```

**PHP - Controller**

```
<?php

require_once("../Model/dbmanager.php");

session_start();
class AuctionController{

    public function __construct($metodo){

        // $this->$metodo();
    }

    public static function ejecuta($metodo){
        self::$metodo();
    }

    public function tiempoSubasta(){
        $codS = $_POST['codSubasta'];
        $fechaFin = DbManager::getFF($codS);
        if($fechaFin==-1){
            echo "ERROR";
        }else{

            echo json_encode(strtotime($fechaFin),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
        }

    }

}

if(isset($_POST['metodo'])){
    AuctionController::ejecuta($_POST['metodo']);
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}


?>
```

**PHP - BD**

```
<?
class DbManager{
    public static function getConnection(){
        $inst = Conexion::getInstance();
        return $inst->getConnection();
    }

    public static function getFF($codSubasta){
        $connection = self::getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT FechaFin FROM Subasta WHERE CodSubasta =".$codSubasta;
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        if($result){
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            return $row["FechaFin"];
        }else{
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

**PHP - Conexion**

```
<?php
class Conexion{
    protected $con;
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_username = "dwes";
    private $_pass = "abc123.";
    private $_database = "subastas";
    protected static $instance;
    private function __construct(){
        $this->con = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username,$this->_pass, $this->_database);

        // Error handling
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Failed to conenct to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(),
                 E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->con;
    }
    /**
        @return instance
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
?>
```

Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda.